# Cant send table data to mvc controller using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Hello I Have a Model Like

```
public class Delivery
{
    public string Description{get,set}
    public string Quantity {get,set}
    public Date Date{get,set}
    public Int LoactionId {get,set}
}
```

I have an html dynamic generated table with data  and i used ajax to send those data to controller  the code is

```
function Save(){ 
    var delivery =[];


    $('#table2 tbody').each(function () {

        delivery.push({
            Description:$(this).closest('tr').find('#description').text();
        Quantity:$(this).closest('tr').find('input[name="last_name[]"]').val();
        Date:  $(this).closest('tr').find('.datepicker_recurring_start').val();
        LocationId:$(this).closest('tr').find("#sel option:selected").val(); 
    });

    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "Save/Create/",
        data: JSON.stringify({ Delivery: delivery }),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert('Success')
        },
        error: function (x, e) {
            alert('Failed')
        }
    });

}
```

And My Action method is

```
public JsonResult Create(List<Delivery> Delivery )
{
}
```

But its not working  Its not getting data from the table .I dont know what I am missing or my code is wrong . If there any way that i can pass one by one not using array anyone can suggest me that . I also added a fiddle of that dynamic table now some are empty but  note that each one will have value

Thanks for help.

[Dynamic generated table](https://jsfiddle.net/0q3e7Lcz/1/)

Comment: For a start, your MVC action is expecting a single `Delivery` object, but you're pushing an array.  Try changing the action signature to :  `public JsonResult Create(IList<Delivery> delivery)`

Comment: And your `$.each()` block makes no sense (unless you have multiple `<tbody>` elements each with one `<tr>` element - I assume you want to loop through the `<tr>` elements

Comment: Err, don't change it in the question, change it in your code.  Or are you fixing a typo?

Comment: No sorry i missed to add this sorry its already there.

Comment: Not getting *all data* - is it getting *some data*?  Is `Loaction` a typo in the question or is that in your code as well?

Comment: I mean its not getting any data at all.Sorry for typing mistakes

Comment: That's ok, that's what comments are for - to clarify.

Comment: @freedomn-m, All OP is posting is `undefined` based on their loop.

Comment: You need to post your html for the table so your script can be corrected

Comment: Show relevant html and also inspect `delivery ` array before you send it

Comment: If you only want to pass one, then don't collate into an array or loop through array (but that will give bad performance): `data: { Delivery: delivery[0] },`

Comment: As per @StephenMuecke comment: `$('#table2 tbody tr').each(function () { ..  Description:$(this).find('#description').text(); `  although you should use classes, not IDs on table rows as IDs should be unique for the whole document.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I was looking at the MVC part (which turned out to be a typo when creating the question) and missed the obvious jquery loop incorrectness :(

Comment: The table is unique i can assure you  and its dynamically created. What i need to do pass every rows values.

Comment: We cannot help unless you show the html!

Comment: Not the table, the `ID`s in the inputs on each row, as shown by your code: `[each row].find("#description")`

Comment: I added the table in the fiddle @StephenMuecke

Comment: The code needs to be in the question (not a link to a fiddle which is not even opening)

Comment: its very big thats why i added it in the fiddle  now the link is working

Comment: Just add the html for a typical row. And you have other problems including duplicate `id` attributes which is invalid html.

Answer (score 0):

first i would test with a simple array not generated from foreach loop, just to check where is the problem. for example:

```
    var delivery  = [
        {Description:'1', Quantity:1, Date:'03.02.2017', LocationId:2  },
        { Description:'1', Quantity:1, Date:'03.02.2017', LocationId:2  }
    ];
```

and then i would change the parameter type in the backend method to be a array, like this:

```
    public JsonResult Create(Delivery[] Delivery)
 {
 }
```

Comment: `List<Delivery>` will map the same as `Delivery[]` in MVC

Comment: i didn't say other than this. wanted to keep it consistent. thanks for thr hint!!